# "Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string" Using Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am new to PS. I have what should be a very simple script that needs to detect a substring in lines of a file...

```
$data = get-content "C:\temp\test.log"
foreach($line in $data)
{
   if($line.length -gt 50){
   write-host $line.length
   write-host $data.substring(39,3)
   }
```

}

Each line in the file is over 100 char's long. I need to read 3 characters at column 30 in the file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
write-host $data.substring(39,3)
```

with

```
write-host $line.substring(39,3)
```

;)

Comment: Perfect Thanks!!! Wow. I guess it was too early in the morning when I did this ;-)